# Kafka Listener is not working! It is isolated in intranet

Tags: apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-networking

My Kafka node is hosted in Google Cloud Dataproc. However, we realized that the Kafka installed through default initialization script is set up in such a way that it only allows intranet access. It is completely isolated from the outside world. The producer outside the google cloud network can't publish the message to Kafka and the Kafka message can't chain to its extranet subscriber.

**Remark**

I have whitelisted the producer IP

After read thru the other StackOverflow, blog post and documentation. I think it could due to `advertised.listeners` parts of `Socket Server Settings` in `/usr/lib/kafka/server.properties`.

**First solution**

> I added `advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://[External_IP]:19092`
>
> then `sudo /etc/init.d/kafka-server restart`

[image: Kafka Restart Successfully]

**OUTCOME**

However, when I trying to Kafkacat or telnet, it always failed. I also tested advertised.listeners with  various port
[image: Ping Success, telnet and kafkacat failed]

**Second solution** from https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/
[image]

```
############################# Server Basics #############################

# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id=0

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
#

# Hostname and port the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not set,
# it uses the value for "listeners" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value
# returned from java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().


->>>>>>> I added below listener config according to https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

listeners=INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:19092
listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
advertised.listeners=EXTERNAL://[External_IP]:19092,INTERNAL://[Internal_IP]:9092
inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL
```

**OUTCOME**

It's the same result as above, Not Working.

**Firewall Rules** [Updated]

This is my current firewall rules config. Am I doing a mistake?
[image: Firewall Rules]

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: Both of the solutions that mentions above is taken from others post.

Comment: Ping is working... What error is telnet or `nc -vz IP 19092` giving?

Comment: @cricket_007 after executing the command. 
nc: connect to 34.xx.xx.xx port 19092 (tcp) failed: Connection timed out

Comment: Alright, sounds like you've not opened connections to that port from the Dataproc / GCE network settings... Have you tried using the same command within the Cloud shell?

Comment: Most probably you need to properly [configure firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) to allow access.

Comment: @IgorDvorzhak you mean set `Protocols and ports = all `  ?
I already whitelisted all the producers and allow them to access all the ports.
@cricket_007 I tried to telnet from cloud shells and different worker nodes. All of them can't get responses from the [External IP] port.

Comment: Currently, my workaround is
1) landing all transaction data in cloud SQL 
2) CDC from compute engine and publish to Dataproc Kafka [Internal IP ]:9092(since Kafka can only be reached via the intranet.

this fool idea adds 2 seconds latency to my pipeline.

Comment: @IgorDvorzhak I updated the post with firewall rules screenshot.

Comment: I'd suggest you first verify firewall config is correct. You can stop Kafka and run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 19092` on the VM, then try to access it with `curl http://<external-ip>:19092` from your local machine.

Comment: Also, have you updated the `advertised.listeners` with external IPs for all nodes of your Kafka cluster?

Comment: Cloud shell should be using the internal listener, not external. Note: Kafka is not Hadoop, and you probably shouldn't open all ports from all IP ranges. And is that rule for the whole project? Do you need to attach the rule to GCE instances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what worked for my cluster:

I've set the following properties from the second solution:

```
listeners=INTERNAL://0.0.0.0:9092,EXTERNAL://0.0.0.0:19092
listener.security.protocol.map=INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
advertised.listeners=EXTERNAL://[External_IP]:19092,INTERNAL://[Internal_IP]:9092
inter.broker.listener.name=INTERNAL
```

I've created a firewall rule opening port 19092 to my personal development machine IP and applied it to the network. **From my machine**, I've tried to telnet the kafka server and I got:

```
$ telnet [EXTERNAL-IP] 19092
Trying [EXTERNAL-IP]...
Connected to [EXTERNAL-IP].
Escape character is '^]'.
```

I then tried to use kafkacat, and got an error. Running in debug, I saw the error was because I have not set any topics:

```
%7|1578351264.551|METADATA|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: [EXTERNAL-IP]:19092/bootstrap: ===== Received metadata: application requested =====
%7|1578351264.551|METADATA|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: [EXTERNAL-IP]:19092/bootstrap: ClusterId: jYxfi6zzR0euAovYyKCFZg, ControllerId: -1
%7|1578351264.551|METADATA|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: [EXTERNAL-IP]:19092/bootstrap: 0 brokers, 0 topics
%7|1578351264.551|METADATA|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: [EXTERNAL-IP]:19092/bootstrap: No brokers or topics in metadata: should retry
%7|1578351264.551|REQERR|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:main]: [EXTERNAL-IP]:19092/bootstrap: MetadataRequest failed: Local: Partial response: explicit actions Retry
%7|1578351264.551|RETRY|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:[EXTERNAL-IP]:19092/bootstrap]: [EXTERNAL-IP]:19092/bootstrap: Retrying MetadataRequest (v2, 25 bytes, retry 1/2, prev CorrId 3) in 100ms
```

Please notice that I've tried to connect to the kafka server from outside to the cluster. In the questions, the telnet and kafkacat are running on the same machine as the kafka server (kafka-tng-w-0).

Comment: How do you restart the Kafka service? Is my restart script `sudo /etc/init.d/kafka-server restart ` correct?  Should I restart the entire Kafka included zookeeper?

Comment: Yes, I ran `sudo /etc/init.d/kafka-server restart`, notice you can also do that in an initialization script

Comment: Following your setup steps. Now seems like a firewall rules issue. I already updated the figure 4. Can you help me to check am I set up the rules correctly?

Comment: The field should contain an comma delimited list of IP addresses (a.b.c.d) or CIDR masks (a.b.c.d/n). It should contain the address of the machine running the producer or the machine you are running your tests from.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Sorry for misleading. Let said, in this case, I only allow tcp:19092 for inbound access. Do we need any other firewall rules to apply?

Comment: After I put CIDR masks = 0.0.0.0/0. I can successfully telnet the [external_IP]port.
Did you encounter "topic leader not found" after applied the ` properties from the second solution` when you accessing the consumer? /usr/lib/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server [External_IP]:19092 --topic test-topic

Comment: Please notice that 0.0.0.0/0 effectively opens the server to the entire world! I'd strongly suggest to narrow it down. Also, please make sure that Kafka is properly configured for your needs (has the right topics for example) before trying to access it with kafka clients

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample docker-compose.yaml file.

```
version: '2'

services:

  zookeeper:
    image: strimzi/kafka:0.20.0-kafka-2.6.0
    command: [
      "sh", "-c",
      "bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties"
    ]
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      LOG_DIR: /tmp/logs

  kafka:
    image: strimzi/kafka:0.20.0-kafka-2.6.0 
    command: [
      "sh", "-c",
      "bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties --override 
listeners=$${KAFKA_LISTENERS} --override 
advertised.listeners=$${KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS} --override 
zookeeper.connect=$${KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT}"
    ]
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      LOG_DIR: "/tmp/logs"
      # Dev GQ - Laptop
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://172.23.240.1:9092
      # AWS Pre-Prod  
      #KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://11.122.200.229:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
```

And here is a sample Quarkus application.properties file with kafka bootstrap server configured as advertised listeners in docker-compose.yaml.

```
# Configure the SmallRye Kafka connector
# Dev GQ - Laptop
mp.messaging.connector.smallrye-kafka.bootstrap.servers=172.23.240.1:9092
# AWS Pre-Prod
#mp.messaging.connector.smallrye-kafka.bootstrap.servers=11.122.200.229:9092
quarkus.kafka.health.enabled=true

# Configure the Kafka sink (we write to it)
mp.messaging.outgoing.generated-price.connector=smallrye-kafka
mp.messaging.outgoing.generated-price.topic=prices
mp.messaging.outgoing.generated-price.value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer

# Configure the Kafka source (we read from it)
mp.messaging.incoming.prices.connector=smallrye-kafka
mp.messaging.incoming.prices.topic=prices
# ..... more codes
```

Answer (score 0):

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
 zookeeper:
  image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
  ports:
   - "2181:2181"
 kafka:
  image: wurstmeister/kafka
  hostname: kafka
  ports:
   - "9093:9093"
   - "9092:9092"
  environment:
   TZ: CST-8
   KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 3
   KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
   KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
   KAFKA_LISTENERS: INSIDE://:9092,OUTSIDE://:9093
   KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INSIDE://kafka:9092,OUTSIDE://${Your_External_IP}:9093
   KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
   KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INSIDE
  volumes:
   - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  links:
   - zookeeper
```